# How can I convert Sql query to Linq and its equivalent with Join() method in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

```sql
select 
    a.*
from
    Article a join 
    ArticleTag at on a.Id = at.ArticleId join
    Tag t on at.TagId = t.Id 
where
    t.Id=8
```

Also I have access to `IQueryable<Article>`, `IQueryable<Tag>`and `IQueryable<ArticleTag>` objects.

How can I convert this Sql query to Linq and its equivalent with `Join()` method and lambda expression in Entity Framework Core?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
var innerJoinQuery =
    from a in Article
    join at in ArticleTag on a.Id equals at.ArticleId
    where at.TagId == 8
    select a;
```

This is most performant way of doing it. There could be tricky "things" EF can do if you use LINQ extensions

But if you insist...

```cs
var innerJoinResult = 
    Articles.Join(ArticleTags.Where(x => x.TagId == 8),
                  a => a.Id,
                  at => at.ArticleId,  
                  (a, at) => a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have IQueryable< ArticleTag > articleTags, list of articles can be selected by

```
articleTags.Where(a => a.Tag.id = 8).Select (a -> a.ArticleTag );
```